# Simple html dom parser for laravel 5

Tags: html, parsing, dom, laravel

where I can find simple html dom parser for laravel 5?
I'm looking for somethink like this: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: There are [ported packages available](https://packagist.org/search/?q=simple%20html%20dom) on Packagist which you can install with Composer and use in Laravel? Or do you need Laravel Service Providers and/or Facades?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I recommend [FriendsOfPHP/Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte), it's deservedly one of the most popular PHP crawlers on GitHub.

**Controller**

```
$crawler->filter('a[class="o_title"][href]')->each(function ($node) {
    $hrefs[] = $node->attr('href'); 
});

return view('some-template', ['hrefs' => $hrefs]);
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($hrefs as $href)
    {{ $href }}
@endforeach
```

In your case it will be:

```
$crawler = $client->request(
    'GET', 
    'http://www.oglaszamy24.pl/ogloszenia/nieruchomosci/domy/?std=1&results=100000'
);
$text = $crawler->filter('.resultpages_current')->text();
$numPages = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $text));
```

Comment: how get list of href. I use somethink like this but it return 1 line: $info = $crawler->filter('a[class="o_title"][href]')->attr('href');

Comment: ``$crawler->filter('a[class="o_title"][href]')->each(function ($node) { $hrefs[] = $node->attr('href'); });``

Comment: nice. But how I can display it in ma view?

Comment: thanks, maybe you can tell me, how I can count how much pages are on website (for example. < 1 2 3 4 5 ... 100 ... > )

Comment: can you give me the url which you want to parse so I can look at html and give you exact answer?

Comment: just updated answer to contain working solution for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend paquettg, It's simple and allow update dom too

https://packagist.org/packages/paquettg/php-html-parser?fbclid=IwAR0j7MMlMc5eY3qQfHbXuqd0AVocjpIoHBxUJWgUIUWRuAeDsFOEDLCIdwk